# How to test if SQL Server database is in Single User Mode

Tags: sql-server

How can I test if the SQL Server database is in Single User Mode in a SQL script?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can check the `sys.databases` view ...

```
if (SELECT user_access_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'YourDb') 
                                                            = 'SINGLE_USER'
    begin
       print 'It is in single user mode!'
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases 
                  WHERE name = 'YourDb' AND user_access_desc = 'SINGLE_USER') = 1 THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 END AS SingleUserMode;
```